# How to send messages over RDMA (Infiniband) from within KVM code to another instance of KVM?

Tags: linux, kernel, kvm, infiniband, rdma

I am trying to setup an **RDMA channel** between two instances of **KVM**. I want to send a simple string between the two instances using **RDMA (Infiniband) Verbs API** from **inside the hypervisor**. I don't want to do anything on the user-space - **purely kernel space should be involved**.

I have come across sample code for the Verbs API but that is only relevant to the user-space. Can someone please point me to some sample code for this?

*(Ideally I would want to do this from inside the page fault handler, but the sample code will probably not be specific to where it is being inserted in the hypervisor so this is just an extra bit of information.)*

Answer (score 0):

There are modules in the kernel that use RDMA under `drivers/infiniband/ulp`, although since they are production code and not a sample they might be more complex than what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I'm looking for a simple example to open an RDMA channel and pass strings. Can you help with that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have such an example at hand.